# Database.SaveResult.getId() returns null

Tags: apex, update, id

I'm trying to update an account list and I need to get the Ids when the update fails.

I use the `getId()` method but for accounts which fail I get `null`.

It's an update so my account already has an Id.

Is it normal ? If it is, how can I get the Ids list of non-updated accounts ?

Here is my code :

```
List<Account> accountsList = [select Id from Account];

for(Account a : accountsList) {
    a.Name = 'Test',
}

List<Database.SaveResult> res = Database.update(accountsList, false);

for (Database.SaveResult s : res) {
    if (!s.isSuccess()) {
        system.debug(s.getId()); // I get null here
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can match the updated records with the `Database.SaveResults` using a list iterator, which will give you access to the original record:

```
List<Account> accountsList = [select Id from Account];

for(Account a : accountsList) {
    a.Name = 'Test',
}

List<Database.SaveResult> res = Database.update(accountsList, false);

//for (Database.SaveResult s : res) { //replaced by the following line
for (Integer i = 0; i < accountsList.size(); i++) {
    Database.SaveResult s = res[i];
    Account origRecord = accountsList[i];
    if (!s.isSuccess()) {
        system.debug(s.getId()); // I get null here
        system.debug(origRecord.Id); //This should be the Id you're looking for
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

See the SaveResult class docs: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm

and the example use:

```
// Iterate through each returned result
for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
    if (sr.isSuccess()) {
        // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
        System.debug('Successfully inserted account. Account ID: ' + sr.getId());
    }
    else {
        // Operation failed, so get all errors                
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('Account fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
        }
    }
}
```

**The docs say that the getId() method only returns on success.**

> If this field contains a value, the object was successfully inserted
>   or updated. If this field is empty, the operation was not successful
>   for that object.

Comment: Yes I read it. Is there a workaround to get the IDs ?

Comment: You could get the Ids of all the successfully updated accounts and then use that list to figure out which ones didn't update.