# Partial success for insert, update, delete

Tags: apex, dml, database

Not long time ago I decided to use `insert`, `update`, `delete` methods of `Database` class and its optional 2nd parameter *allOrNone* with `false` as value.

But I found calling `getId` from the result does not return an Id for a failed record. It makes sense for `insert`, but `update` and `delete`?

How can I process partial success for `insert`, `update` and `delete` operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the list of ids you attempted to update/delete to the list of id's you collect with getid() that succeeded to determine which records failed.

If you iterate on the ids in your original collection, you can use the [Error Class getMessage() method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_error.htm#apex_Database_Error_getMessage) to determine the actual error for each record Id which didn't update/delete successfully.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. I didn't think about this, because I created a method to which I pass SaveResult array and where I tried to get all information.

Answer (score -1):

**getId()**
Returns the ID of the sObject you were trying to insert or update.

> **Usage**
>  If this field contains a value, the object was successfully inserted or updated. If this field is empty, the
>   operation was not successful for that object.

More details are listed at this question,
[Database.SaveResult.getId() returns null](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54737/database-saveresult-getid-returns-null)

Ref : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm

Comment: I saw this. This fact leads me to write a question on SO.